# Delete some word in richtextbox

Tags: c#

I have RTB with this text :

```
2016-01-01T10:47:19Z Info {"message":"stopped establish worker"}
2016-01-01T10:47:19Z Info {"message":"stop establishing"}
2016-01-01T10:47:25Z Alert {"message":"DoStatusRequest failed for 188.166.29.241"]
```

my question is , what code that can make my RTB only display text like this

```
stopped establish worker
stop establishing
DoStatusRequest failed for 188.166.29.241
```

i have used this code but nothing happen.

```
List<string> finalLines = richTextBox1.Lines.ToList();
finalLines.RemoveAll(x => x.StartsWith("2016") && x.EndsWith("message\":\""));
richTextBox1.Lines = finalLines.ToArray();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tried _anything_ to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people _might_ show theirs. Please  read [FAQ] and [ask] as a start..

Comment: You have shown absolutely no effort in trying to solve this issue yourself.  I would suggest to attempt doing it yourself and if you come across a programming problem that you definitely can't solve after some research and putting in enough effort, then you should ask a questions regarding it here.

Comment: Come on, he needs some help not to be voted down.

Comment: Use a regex. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Jelly The original post had no code and just the requirement of what needs to be accomplished.  Lack of effort is not something one should reward.  However, once some code has been posted, I'm all for pushing the person in the right direction, as they're demonstrating the fact that they're trying.  On many of my answers I've went well beyond what is needed to help posters, because they've demonstrated great effort.

Comment: @B.K: Thanks for your comment but I'm afraid SO is heading in the wrong direction. There's too much hostility towards newbies. We all know homework should be done before a question gets asked. Let's not forget though that those new comers may not know rules, after all, they're all new but some users on SO (for some reason) just fly to down vote which scares visitors. I don't know what satisfaction does they get from doing that.

Comment: @Jelly Hostility? There is no hostility. Both comments, from myself and Soner Gönül explained that effort must be shown and if that happens, help would be provided. Where's hostility in that? We've all been new -- I haven't started programming until three years ago, so I know what it's like to be new. Furthermore, those are the rules of life. In most schools, I would assume, if you come up to the instructor with a question, there's an expectation that you have tried, but failed (keyword: tried). Believe me, there is no hostility coming from here (by the way, I didn't downvote and I rarely do).

Comment: i wasn't implying you or soner gonul i was speaking of a general phenomenon on stackoverflow and i know you didn't downvote (its clear from your comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **two errors** in your code are that you

- assume the [`List.RemoveAll(Predicate<T>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/wdka673a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will remove **parts of the string**. But it will remove each line **entirely** that meets the condition.
- You forgot to include the ending curly in your string match so no line matches.

To solve this kind of task you have two common ways to chose from:

- Using a `RegEx`
- Use string manipulation

In this case going for string manipulation is simple enough:

```
List<string > lines = richTextBox1.Lines.ToList();
lines = lines.Select(x => x.Substring(0, x.Length - 2)
                           .Substring(x.IndexOf("\":\"") + 3)).ToList();
richTextBox1.Lines = lines.ToArray();
```

But whether this is flexible and safe enough will always depend on the peculiarities of the data.

Which is just as true for a `Regex`, but these can be very powerful for working on more dynamic data or for problems where you can make use of their character groups or advanced pattern matching, especially when you don't know if and how many matches there will be.

The above solution is for example not robust against lines that do not fit the matching string; those will not be clipped at the start but will still be trimmed by two characters at the end..

To make it more robust, maybe it would help going for a loop instead of LINQ and adding a few checks..

Here are two examples of how you can create more robust expression using RegEx:

Suppose you want to be sure only to clean up lines starting with four digits you can write:

```
string sNew = Regex.Replace(sOld, "[0-9]{4}.*\":\"", "");
```

This means delete everything ('`.*`', i.e. any character any number of times) that starts with with four digits and ends with '`":"`'.

To delete the ending two characters you can write:

```
string sNew = Regex.Replace(sOld, "..$" "");
```

This means the last two character of the line or string.

If we want to clean only lines ending with an apostrophe and a curly we could write:

```
string sNew = Regex.Replace(sOld, "\"\\}$" "");
```

`$` again means 'end of the line or string'. Also note how we have two levels of **escaping**: We must escape the apostrophe in a `C#` string and we must escape other characters like the backslash and the curly inside a `RegEx`..

With great power there also comes some level of complexity.. Meaning that in producton code RegExes need extra precise and meticulous documentation!

Final example: In your question you have the last line ending with a bracket instead of a curly. Probably a typo, but you could include this variant like this:

```
string sNew = Regex.Replace(sOld, "[\"}\\]]{2}$", "");
```

Can you decipher it?